# Rotate Line graph in R

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

I am trying to create a line graph with rotated x and y axes.

[This is what my graph looks like, but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xbic.jpg)

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDy2L.jpg)

I am using the basic `plot` function in R as I am unfamiliar with `ggplot2`.

My code thus far is:

```
mytab=read.csv("stratotyperidge.csv") 
plot(mytab$meters,mytab$d180,lwd=2,col="darkblue",bty='n',type='b',xlab="Height above base (m)",ylab="d180",main="Stratotype Ridge", horiz=TRUE)
```

But `horiz=TRUE` returns an error, although I have used it with `barplot`. I do not want to save my plot as an image and simply rotate it. I want to plot it like the picture linked above. This specific question has not been answered on SO.

This is what my data looks like:

```
ID# Identifier 1    d180    d13C    meters    
1   JEM 1           -6.5    1.09    0.5
2   JEM 2          -6.99    0.38    0.85
4   JEM 4          -6.94    0.66    10
5   JEM 5          -6.39    0.75    30.8
6   JEM 6          -7.15    0.38    50.2
7   JEM 7          -8.14    0.03    62.15
8   JEM 8A          -7.4    0.33    71
8.5 JEM 8B         -7.21    -0.05   71.4
10  JEM 10         -7.39    0.14    82.4
12  JEM 12         -7.27    1.22    87.5
```

Comment: You do not provide any data.  The axes on your desired graph are not labeled, so we do not know how they relate to your data. You do not say what your current code is producing.  Help us out a little!

Comment: @G5W, please see the newly edited question.

Comment: How does rotating a graph cause a single graph to split into 2 and change the coordinate range? This seems obscure.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I do not need two. Sorry for the confusion. It doesn't change the coordinate range either. This is just a screenshot of the TYPE of graph I want. The data values etc. will be from my table.

Comment: Seems like you simply have to switch `x` and `y` values in the `plot(x, y)`.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius, nope, that is not correct. See the link above or the answer with the check-mark below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are after something like this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(what, value, d180, d13C) %>%
    ggplot(aes(meters, value)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ what, scales = "free_x") +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ID 'Identifier 1'    d180    d13C    meters
1   'JEM 1'           -6.5    1.09    0.5
2   'JEM 2'          -6.99    0.38    0.85
4   'JEM 4'          -6.94    0.66    10
5   'JEM 5'          -6.39    0.75    30.8
6   'JEM 6'          -7.15    0.38    50.2
7   'JEM 7'          -8.14    0.03    62.15
8   'JEM 8A'          -7.4    0.33    71
8.5 'JEM 8B'         -7.21    -0.05   71.4
10  'JEM 10'         -7.39    0.14    82.4
12  'JEM 12'         -7.27    1.22    87.5", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
plot(mytab$meters, mytab$d180, type="l")
```

Try this:

```
plot(mytab$d180, mytab$meters, type="l")
```

You should get something like this:

[image: pic]